# How to add '\' to each '&' with regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a string that contains ampersands. I need to escape each ampersand in the string by adding a '\' before it. How do I do that? I'm very new to regular expressions, so please excuse me if this is a very simple question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for this:

```
$s = str_replace('&', '\\&', $s);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace().

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = "one & two & three";
$str = str_replace('&', '\\&', $str);
```

Comment: You have inverted parameters : search | replace | subject

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace('&', '\\&', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = str_replace('&', '\\&', $string);
```